# Error installing/building Caldecott

Tags: rubygems, appfog, vmc

My environment:

- Windows 8 x64
- RubyInstaller:
- Ruby 1.9.3-p392
- DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe

(Note: previously tried Ruby 2.0 and associated dev kit and got compile error. Then saw 1.9.2 req and installed that separately, careful not to mix them.)

Steps:

1. Updated PATH, installed DevKit per instructions.
2. gem update --system
3. gem install af (using AppFog, a CloudFoundry partner)

Then, from the [gem instructions](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html), I run:

gem install caldecott --no-rdoc --no-ri

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

Any idea why I'm getting that? As a follow up, I followed the test procedure in the [DevKit instructions](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit):

- gem install json --platform=ruby
- ruby -rubygems -e "require 'json';puts JSON.load('[42]').inspect"

Results were as predeicted, so this appears to be only for caldecott.

Answer (score 0):

well, i had same experienced
i tried to clean my geb cache with delete all files in C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\cache
and it works ^^

Comment: Thank you, I had tried that before posting but it doesn't work for me. I now see there's also a new version of CF coming out, so I'm not sure what this means. The new instructions do not mention Caldecott at all, but who knows when this will be released and when AppFog will update.